# Faulting application name: SDLWeb8CM.exe, version: 8.1.1.80

Tags: web8, installation

As per Instillation Guide I have created User and add him in local admin group and login with that user and rt click on SDLWeb8CM.exe and selected "Run As Administrator"

I got the following error "Faulting application name: SDLWeb8CM.exe, version: 8.1.1.80"

What I am missing? I have verified the prerequisites for CMS installation and we have all prerequisites.

Event log:
Faulting application name: SDLWeb8CM.exe, version: 8.1.1.80, time stamp: 0x5432d975
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18340, time stamp: 0x5736541b
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00014878
Faulting process id: 0x1174
Faulting application start time: 0x01d215b161f6d217
Faulting application path: C:\Software\Web 8.1.1\SDL Web 8.1.1 release\Content Manager\SDLWeb8CM.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: a098f0d2-81a4-11e6-80c8-005056a93c59
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: When installer fails, it generates a log file and provides link to the log file. Check that log file for exact error and share that details.

Comment: The error is before installer starts that's why I am not getting any logs

Comment: Then reach out to SDL support, they can help you in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Randomly verifying IIS settings we received the error in C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config once we fixed the errors in applicationHost.config I am able to start the installation wizard.